# ImportError: No module named newspaper

Tags: python, python-newspaper

I am trying to build a python program that will display various headlines from certain news sites. I used pip to install the module newspaper, but when I run the program, I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named newspaper

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the module in the same folder as your program?

Comment: Did you follow those requirements during the install ? http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/install.html#install

Comment: Also if you are using python 3, you should use `pip install newspaper3k`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, refer to the user guide doc mentioned above.  But, NOTE that Python3 is:

```
pip install newspaper3k
```

and Python 2.x is:

```
pip install newspaper
```

NOTE: you may need to use *sudo* on some systems to install with pip.  Ex:

```
sudo pip install newspaper
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type at the terminal

`pip install newspaper3k`